# Spring Boot: Configure custom MethodSecurityExpressionOperations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

I am trouble shooting a spring boot security configuration that I once had working, but now is not recognizing my custom definitions. My goal was to protect all of our Services with method level security in Spring with custom annotations.

When I start the service my CustomMethodSecurityConfig is instantiated and does call createExpressionHandler(), but when I make the request to the service it does not call createSecurityExpressionRoot(...) on my CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler, but on the DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.

I appreciate any insights anyone may be able to provide as to why Spring Security is not recognizing my expressions defined in my CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot.

Here is a snippet of my GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class CustomMethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

  private final MyService1 myService1;
  private final MyService2 myService2;
  private final MyService3 myService3;

  @Autowired
  public CustomMethodSecurityConfig(MyService1 myService1, MyService2 myService2,
                                    MyService3 myService3) {
    this.myService1 = myService1;
    this.myService2 = myService2;
    this.myService3 = myService3;
  }

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
        new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler(myService1, myService2, myService3);
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator());
    return expressionHandler;
  }
}
```

Here is a snippet of my DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler class

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

  private final MyService1 myService1;
  private final MyService2 myService2;
  private final MyService3 myService3;
  private AuthenticationTrustResolver trustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

  public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler(MyService1 myService1, MyService2 myService2,
                                               MyService3 myService3) {
    this.myService1 = myService1;
    this.myService2 = myService2;
    this.myService3 = myService3;
  }

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication,
                                                                            MethodInvocation invocation) {
    CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication,
                                                                                     myService1,
                                                                                     myService2,
                                                                                     myService3);

    root.setPermissionEvaluator(getPermissionEvaluator());
    root.setTrustResolver(this.trustResolver);
    root.setRoleHierarchy(getRoleHierarchy());

    return root;
  }
}
```

Here is the snippet of my SecurityExpressionRoot, this is where I am defining my SpEL expressions which I use in annotations on my Services. I have only included a simplified, isUser as an example. What these methods do isn't important, but the fact that they are visible.

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot
    implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

  private Object filterObject;
  private Object returnObject;

  private MyService1 myService1;
  private MyService2 myService2;
  private MyService3 myService3;

  public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(
      Authentication authentication,
      MyService1 myService1,
      MyService2 myService2,
      MyService3 myService3) {
    super(authentication);
    this.myService1 = myService1;
    this.myService2 = myService2;
    this.myService3 = myService3;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getFilterObject() {
    return this.filterObject;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getReturnObject() {
    return this.returnObject;
  }

  @Override
  public void setFilterObject(Object obj) {
    this.filterObject = obj;
  }

  @Override
  public void setReturnObject(Object obj) {
    this.returnObject = obj;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getThis() {
    return this;
  }

  //All custom SpEL methods
  public boolean isUser(Long userId) {
    SecurityUser user = (SecurityUser) this.getPrincipal();
    return user.getUserId() == userId;
  }

  ...

}
```

And finally here is a snippet of my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which is used in tandem, it verifies the external authentication token from our UAA server.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true,
    proxyTargetClass = true)
public class ServiceSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private final TokenCheckService _tokenCheckService;

  @Autowired
  ServiceSecurityConfig(TokenCheckService tokenCheckService) {
    _tokenCheckService = tokenCheckService;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(new TokenAuthenticationProvider(_tokenCheckService));
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/**");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .anonymous()
              .disable()
            .csrf()
              .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
              .authenticationEntryPoint(new UnAuthorizedEntryPoint())
              .and()
            .sessionManagement()
              .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
              .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

Edit:
I seem to think it is an issue with my WebDecisionVoters being overridden during intialization. If I have a breakpoint in the Affirmative constructor

```
AffirmativeBased(List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters)
```

I can see AffirmativeBased being instantiated with 3 decision voters, one of which is a PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter, which contains a reference to my expression handler. I believe this is being created by bean instantiation of the methodSecurityInterceptor.

When I continue the breakpoint I again hit the same Affirmative based constructor, but with only one decision voter, a WebExperssionVoter with a reference to an instance of DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler. I believe this is being created by bean instantiation of the springSecurityFilterChain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by following the steps in [Custom SecurityExpression with Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090783/spring-4-custom-securityexpression-with-service). The issue appears to have been with my autowired services that were separate from security. MyService1, MyService2, and MyService3 causing the issues and removing them allowed security to work.

Any additional services must be set in createSecurityExpressionRoot of the class that extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.

```
@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
    CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(authentication);
    // Other initialization
    root.setMyService1(applicationContext.getBean(MyService1.class));
    root.setMyService2(applicationContext.getBean(MyService2.class));
    root.setMyService3(applicationContext.getBean(MyService3.class));
    return root;
}
```