# spring-security: CglibAopProxy not intercepting method call for GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

I am trying to extend GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration with the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation. I have a separate configuration class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with the @EnableWebSecurity annotation.

If I place the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity on my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and not on my GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration class I am able to see in CglibAopProxy that the method is being intercepted and then invoked. If I remove @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and place it on GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration I no longer see any method interception.

Are the two configurations conflicting? Does anyone have any idea why my methods are no longer properly being invoked after configuring GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration. I hope to implement method security by extending GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration so I can provide my own handler and expression root.

I can provide code snippets if needed.

Thanks,
Civerooni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by the answer in the question [Spring Boot: Configure custom MethodSecurityExpressionOperations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224516/spring-boot-configure-custom-methodsecurityexpressionoperations). I am not 100% sure why Autowiring my own services, registering them as beans was preventing the method intercept for happening. I suspect it was because it was using different application contexts.