# hasAccess Method not found in docker spring boot Custom SecurityExpressionRoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I've created a custom SecurityExpressionRoot which has a method called hasAccess() where i provide module name and permission everything is working fine on local i am using the VSCode with Spring Boot Dashboard to run my application when i try to access any end point which has method on controller **@PreAuthorize("hasAccess('ModuleKey','Permission')")** is working fine and logic work fine but the issue is when i deploy my application on docker and try to access my end point which have the @PreAuthorize annomation is give error that the hasAccess function not found below is complete error detail which i get from docker container logs can any one help me how can i fix this issue is there anything related to docker side setting or i am missing any thing?

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasAccess('Module','Permission')'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method hasAccess(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot
```

I've already check the classpath list on my jar file and i can see the class name AuthorizeRoot is present on the list which contain the hasAccess method I've follow the below link to implement that

[Spring Boot: Configure custom MethodSecurityExpressionOperations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224516/spring-boot-configure-custom-methodsecurityexpressionoperations)